# App is crashing while using Google Sign in for iOS with AssertionFailure

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-signin

I tried to implement Google Sign in for iOS according to the docs - [iOS implentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?configured=true). But the app is crashing with an error while calling

`[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError: &configureError];`

in my App Delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Error :-

`Assertion failure in void validateGoogleSignInWithURLSchemes(NSArray *__strong)(), googlemac/iPhone/Greenhouse/Source/GGLURLSchemeUtil.m:39`

I have added `GoogleService-Info.plist` to the target resources and also added URL Types for `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` and Bundle Identifier as explained in the docs and also referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743123/uncaught-nsinvalidargumentexception-when-using-google-sign-in-for-ios).

Is there something I am missing or what should I do to fix the same?

Answer (score 2):

It was due to a simple spelling mistake. I had my Bundle Identifier wrong in the URL scheme while adding URL Types.

Please suggest if it's better to delete this question. I will delete the same.

Comment: It actually helped me :) Did the same mistake!

Comment: One more thing that wasted my time. REVERSED_CLIENT_ID does not mean to enter the constant as it is. It mean the the string value of REVERSED_CLIENT_ID stored in your GoogleService-Info.plist file.